# Strange pylint errors

Tags: python, pylint

I want to add linter to my github repository, and during tests on dummy code I got strange results.

Code:

```py
"""
Dummy module for pylint tests
"""

def is_prime(num):
    """ Checking if a number is prime """
    if num > 1:
        for i in range(2, num//2):
            if (num % i) == 0:
                #print(num, "is not a prime number")
                break
        else:
            print(num, "is a prime number")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for x in range(2,100000):
        is_prime(x)
```

I got something like this:

```
pylint .\pytest.py
*************
<?>:16:4: W0622: Redefining built-in 'exit' (redefined-builtin)
*************
<?>:4:4: W0611: Unused import _pytest.mark (unused-import)
************* 
<?>:5:4: W0611: Unused import _pytest.recwarn (unused-import)                                                           ************* 
<?>:6:4: W0611: Unused import _pytest.runner (unused-import)                                                            ************* 
<?>:7:4: W0611: Unused import _pytest.python (unused-import)
************* 
<?>:8:4: W0611: Unused import _pytest.skipping (unused-import)                                                          *************  
<?>:9:4: W0611: Unused import _pytest.assertion (unused-import)                                                         ************* 
<?>:36:4: W0611: Unused import _pytest.freeze_support (unused-import)                                                   ************* 
<?>:40:8: W0611: Unused import _pytest.genscript (unused-import)                                                        ************* 
<?>:46:4: W0611: Unused import _pytest.debugging (unused-import)                                                        ************* 
<?>:50:8: W0611: Unused import _pytest.pdb (unused-import)                                                              ************* 
<?>:56:4: W0611: Unused import _pytest.fixtures (unused-import)                                                                                                                                                                                 -----------------------------------                                                                                     Your code has been rated at 0.00/10
```

What is it about? Where did these results come from?

Yes, I can disable W0611 and W0622, but that's not the point.

Comment: So, is your file called `pytest.py`? Perhaps you should rename it to something which is not like something in the python standard library.

Comment: Thank you @quamrana change file name solves the problem. I feel silly :/

Answer (score 0):

## Change the file name

Similar issue: [pylint files gets imported when a file has the same name as one of pylint's files](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/2258)

> So the super silly bug is that if your file is named config.py, then pylint imports its own config.py file

Pylint import the files you want to check. If it is a python builtin library or a installed tier library, it will check this lib instead.